# Gvim regex: find matching XML tag pairs, non-greedy

Tags: regex, vim

So I have the following sample XML on a single line:

```
<foo>123</foo>   <foo>456</foo>  <bar>abc</bar> <foo>789</foo>   <foo>0AB</foo>   <bar>def</bar>
```

I'm looking for a regex which matches the first pair of `<foo>` tags, and which stops at the first `<bar>`

I'm trying solutions around:

```
/<foo>.\+<\/foo>.\+<bar
```

But this matches the entire thing. How do I get it to stop at the first `<bar>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because by default, regular expressions are greedy; that is, they match as much data as possible.  However, in this case, what you want is a non-greedy regex so you match only the first part.

```
<foo>.\{-}<\/foo>.\{-}<bar
```

The pattern `\{-}` is equivalent to `*`, but is non-greedy, like Perl's `*?`.  See `:help non-greedy` for more details.

As a side note, you cannot parse HTML or XML in the general case with regular expressions (since regexes are not powerful enough), but in this case I assume that you have a limited subset of data where this is good enough.